# Mindmap won't progress correctly in my beamer presentation

Tags: tikz-pgf, mindmaps

I'm making a mindmap in my beamer presentation. The mindmap either disregards `grow cyclic` and everything goes to the right/east of the mindmap, or the siblings always align eastward, rather than growing cyclic, similar to a tree.

I'd like my mindmap to look a little like this:

[image]

Instead, the output (from the code below) looks like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}}
    }
}

\makeatletter
\tikzoption{myball color}{\pgfutil@colorlet{tikz@ball}{#1}\def\tikz@shading{myball}\tikz@addmode{\tikz@mode@shadetrue}}
\tikzoption{myball-left color}{\pgfutil@colorlet{tikz@ball}{#1}\def\tikz@shading{myball-left}\tikz@addmode{\tikz@mode@shadetrue}}
\tikzoption{myball-right color}{\pgfutil@colorlet{tikz@ball}{#1}\def\tikz@shading{myball-right}\tikz@addmode{\tikz@mode@shadetrue}}
\tikzoption{myball-lefttop color}{\pgfutil@colorlet{tikz@ball}{#1}\def\tikz@shading{myball-lefttop}\tikz@addmode{\tikz@mode@shadetrue}}
\tikzoption{myball-righttop color}{\pgfutil@colorlet{tikz@ball}{#1}\def\tikz@shading{myball-righttop}\tikz@addmode{\tikz@mode@shadetrue}}
\tikzoption{myball-top color}{\pgfutil@colorlet{tikz@ball}{#1}\def\tikz@shading{myball-top}\tikz@addmode{\tikz@mode@shadetrue}}
\pgfdeclareradialshading[tikz@ball]{myball}{\pgfqpoint{5bp}{10bp}}{%
 color(0bp)=(tikz@ball!30!white);
 color(9bp)=(tikz@ball!75!white);
 color(18bp)=(tikz@ball!90!black);
 color(25bp)=(tikz@ball!70!black);
 color(50bp)=(black)}
 \pgfdeclareradialshading[tikz@ball]{myball-left}{\pgfqpoint{5bp}{-9bp}}{%
 color(0bp)=(tikz@ball!30!white);
 color(15bp)=(tikz@ball!75!white);
 color(25bp)=(tikz@ball!90!black);
 color(40bp)=(tikz@ball!70!black);
 color(70bp)=(black)}
\pgfdeclareradialshading[tikz@ball]{myball-right}{\pgfqpoint{-5bp}{-9bp}}{%
 color(0bp)=(tikz@ball!30!white);
 color(15bp)=(tikz@ball!75!white);
 color(25bp)=(tikz@ball!90!black);
 color(40bp)=(tikz@ball!70!black);
 color(70bp)=(black)} 
 \pgfdeclareradialshading[tikz@ball]{myball-lefttop}{\pgfqpoint{3bp}{7bp}}{%
 color(0bp)=(tikz@ball!30!white);
 color(15bp)=(tikz@ball!75!white);
 color(25bp)=(tikz@ball!90!black);
 color(40bp)=(tikz@ball!70!black);
 color(70bp)=(black)}
\pgfdeclareradialshading[tikz@ball]{myball-righttop}{\pgfqpoint{-3bp}{7bp}}{%
 color(0bp)=(tikz@ball!30!white);
 color(15bp)=(tikz@ball!75!white);
 color(25bp)=(tikz@ball!90!black);
 color(40bp)=(tikz@ball!70!black);
 color(70bp)=(black)} 
\pgfdeclareradialshading[tikz@ball]{myball-top}{\pgfqpoint{0bp}{11bp}}{%
 color(0bp)=(tikz@ball!30!white);
 color(15bp)=(tikz@ball!75!white);
 color(25bp)=(tikz@ball!90!black);
 color(40bp)=(tikz@ball!70!black);
 color(70bp)=(black)} 
\makeatother
\tikzset{level 1 concept/.append style={font=\sf, level distance = 25mm,sibling angle=60}}
\tikzset{level 2 concept/.append style={font=\sf, level distance = 18mm,sibling angle=40}}
\tikzset{level 3 concept/.append style={font=\sf, level distance = 14mm,sibling angle=30}}
\tikzset{mynode/.style={scale=.25}}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap, concept color=red, font=\sf\bf, text=white,scale=0.6, grow cyclic]
\node[concept,mynode,circle,shading=myball,visible on=<1->]{Circulair economie}[clockwise from=45]
    child [sibling angle=250, concept color=orange,visible on=<10->] {node[mynode,circle, myball-top color=orange] (c1){21ste eeuwse verlichting}                                
        child[visible on=<11->]  {node [mynode,circle, myball-left color=orange](c11){Lineaire systemen}}
        child[visible on=<11->]  {node [mynode,circle,myball-left color=orange](c12){Non-lineaire systemen}}
        child[visible on=<11->]  {node [mynode,circle,myball-left color=orange](c13){Inspiratie biosfeer}}                                                   
        child[visible on=<11->]  {node [mynode,circle,myball-left color=orange](c14){Systeemdenken}}
     }
     child [concept color=violet,visible on=<2->]{node [mynode,circle,myball-righttop color=violet, sibling angle=250](c2){Life, Design, Intention}
        child[visible on=<3->] {node [mynode,circle,myball-right color=violet](c21){Biologische cycli}}
        child[visible on=<3->] {node [mynode,circle,myball-right color=violet](c22){Technische cycli}}
        child[visible on=<3->] {node [mynode,circle,myball-right color=violet](c23){Cradle-to-Cradle}}
        child[visible on=<3->] {node [mynode,circle,myball-right color=violet](c24){Whole-systems}}
    }
    child [concept color=blue,visible on=<4->]{node [mynode,circle,myball-right color=violet, clockwise from=250](c3){Energie, materialen}
        child[visible on=<5->] {node [mynode,circle,myball-right color=violet](c31){Energietrends}}
        child[visible on=<5->] {node [mynode,circle,myball-right color=violet](c32){Energie \& Voedsel}}
        child[visible on=<5->] {node [mynode,circle,myball-right color=violet](c33){Slimmere distributie energie}}
        child[visible on=<5->] {node [mynode,circle,myball-right color=violet](c34){Veerkrachtigheid versus efficiëntie}}
        child[visible on=<5->] {node [mynode,circle,myball-right color=violet](c35){Cascading}}
    }
    child [concept color=red,visible on=<6->]{node [mynode,circle,myball-left color=violet](c4){Producten en services}
        child[visible on=<7->] {node [mynode,circle,myball-right color=violet](c41){Circulair design}}
        child[visible on=<7->] {node [mynode,circle,myball-right color=violet](c42){Gebruiker versus consument}}
        child[visible on=<7->] {node [mynode,circle,myball-right color=violet](c43){Design for disassembly}}
        child[visible on=<7->] {node [mynode,circle,myball-right color=violet](c44){Circular financing}}
    }
    child [concept color=yellow,visible on=<8->]{node [mynode,circle,myball-lefttop color=violet](c5){Prijssystemen}
        child[visible on=<9->] {node [mynode,circle,myball-right color=violet](c51){Geld versus goed}}
        child[visible on=<9->] {node [mynode,circle,myball-right color=violet](c52){Belasting en subsidies}}
        child[visible on=<9->] {node [mynode,circle,myball-right color=violet](c53){Welzijn en groei}}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's a confused mind.

Comment: I find that if I use anything to specify the growth manually, after that point, it applies everywhere. So I think `[clockwise from=45]` and `[sibling angle=250]`, for example, effectively override the effect of `grow cyclic`. Try taking them out just to see if that helps as an experiment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A complete solution. There are many `clockwise from=xx` needs to be removed. Further, individual sibling angle=xx is removed and is replaced by automatic allocation of level 1 siblings via

```
sibling angle=360/\the\tikznumberofchildren
```

so that the level 1 siblings are evenly allocated.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,calc}
\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}}
    },
}

\makeatletter
\tikzoption{myball color}{\pgfutil@colorlet{tikz@ball}{#1}\def\tikz@shading{myball}\tikz@addmode{\tikz@mode@shadetrue}}
\tikzoption{myball-left color}{\pgfutil@colorlet{tikz@ball}{#1}\def\tikz@shading{myball-left}\tikz@addmode{\tikz@mode@shadetrue}}
\tikzoption{myball-right color}{\pgfutil@colorlet{tikz@ball}{#1}\def\tikz@shading{myball-right}\tikz@addmode{\tikz@mode@shadetrue}}
\tikzoption{myball-lefttop color}{\pgfutil@colorlet{tikz@ball}{#1}\def\tikz@shading{myball-lefttop}\tikz@addmode{\tikz@mode@shadetrue}}
\tikzoption{myball-righttop color}{\pgfutil@colorlet{tikz@ball}{#1}\def\tikz@shading{myball-righttop}\tikz@addmode{\tikz@mode@shadetrue}}
\tikzoption{myball-top color}{\pgfutil@colorlet{tikz@ball}{#1}\def\tikz@shading{myball-top}\tikz@addmode{\tikz@mode@shadetrue}}
\pgfdeclareradialshading[tikz@ball]{myball}{\pgfqpoint{5bp}{10bp}}{%
 color(0bp)=(tikz@ball!30!white);
 color(9bp)=(tikz@ball!75!white);
 color(18bp)=(tikz@ball!90!black);
 color(25bp)=(tikz@ball!70!black);
 color(50bp)=(black)}
 \pgfdeclareradialshading[tikz@ball]{myball-left}{\pgfqpoint{5bp}{-9bp}}{%
 color(0bp)=(tikz@ball!30!white);
 color(15bp)=(tikz@ball!75!white);
 color(25bp)=(tikz@ball!90!black);
 color(40bp)=(tikz@ball!70!black);
 color(70bp)=(black)}
\pgfdeclareradialshading[tikz@ball]{myball-right}{\pgfqpoint{-5bp}{-9bp}}{%
 color(0bp)=(tikz@ball!30!white);
 color(15bp)=(tikz@ball!75!white);
 color(25bp)=(tikz@ball!90!black);
 color(40bp)=(tikz@ball!70!black);
 color(70bp)=(black)} 
 \pgfdeclareradialshading[tikz@ball]{myball-lefttop}{\pgfqpoint{3bp}{7bp}}{%
 color(0bp)=(tikz@ball!30!white);
 color(15bp)=(tikz@ball!75!white);
 color(25bp)=(tikz@ball!90!black);
 color(40bp)=(tikz@ball!70!black);
 color(70bp)=(black)}
\pgfdeclareradialshading[tikz@ball]{myball-righttop}{\pgfqpoint{-3bp}{7bp}}{%
 color(0bp)=(tikz@ball!30!white);
 color(15bp)=(tikz@ball!75!white);
 color(25bp)=(tikz@ball!90!black);
 color(40bp)=(tikz@ball!70!black);
 color(70bp)=(black)} 
\pgfdeclareradialshading[tikz@ball]{myball-top}{\pgfqpoint{0bp}{11bp}}{%
 color(0bp)=(tikz@ball!30!white);
 color(15bp)=(tikz@ball!75!white);
 color(25bp)=(tikz@ball!90!black);
 color(40bp)=(tikz@ball!70!black);
 color(70bp)=(black)} 
\makeatother
\tikzset{level 1 concept/.append style={font=\sf, level distance = 25mm,sibling angle=360/\the\tikznumberofchildren}}
\tikzset{level 2 concept/.append style={font=\sf, level distance = 18mm,sibling angle=40}}
\tikzset{level 3 concept/.append style={font=\sf, level distance = 14mm,sibling angle=30}}
\tikzset{mynode/.style={scale=.25}}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap, concept color=red, font=\sf\bf, text=white,scale=0.6, grow cyclic
]
\node[concept,mynode,circle,shading=myball,visible on=<1->
]{Circulair economie}[]%clockwise from=45]
    child [concept color=orange,visible on=<10->
] {node[mynode,circle, myball-top color=orange] (c1){21ste eeuwse verlichting}                                
        child[visible on=<11->
]  {node [mynode,circle, myball-left color=orange](c11){Lineaire systemen}}
        child[visible on=<11->
]  {node [mynode,circle,myball-left color=orange](c12){Non-lineaire systemen}}
        child[visible on=<11->
]  {node [mynode,circle,myball-left color=orange](c13){Inspiratie biosfeer}}                                                   
        child[visible on=<11->
]  {node [mynode,circle,myball-left color=orange](c14){Systeemdenken}}
     }
     child [concept color=violet,visible on=<2->
]{node [mynode,circle,myball-righttop color=violet](c2){Life, Design, Intention}
        child[visible on=<3->
] {node [mynode,circle,myball-right color=violet](c21){Biologische cycli}}
        child[visible on=<3->
] {node [mynode,circle,myball-right color=violet](c22){Technische cycli}}
        child[visible on=<3->
] {node [mynode,circle,myball-right color=violet](c23){Cradle-to-Cradle}}
        child[visible on=<3->
] {node [mynode,circle,myball-right color=violet](c24){Whole-systems}}
    }  % ----------------
    child [concept color=blue,visible on=<4->
]{node [mynode,circle,myball-right color=violet](c3){Energie, materialen}
        child[visible on=<5->
] {node [mynode,circle,myball-right color=violet](c31){Energietrends}}
        child[visible on=<5->
] {node [mynode,circle,myball-right color=violet](c32){Energie \& Voedsel}}
        child[visible on=<5->
] {node [mynode,circle,myball-right color=violet](c33){Slimmere distributie energie}}
        child[visible on=<5->
] {node [mynode,circle,myball-right color=violet](c34){Veerkrachtigheid versus efficiëntie}}
        child[visible on=<5->
] {node [mynode,circle,myball-right color=violet](c35){Cascading}}
    }   %----------
    child [concept color=red,visible on=<6->
]{node [mynode,circle,myball-left color=violet](c4){Producten en services}
        child[visible on=<7->
] {node [mynode,circle,myball-right color=violet](c41){Circulair design}}
        child[visible on=<7->
] {node [mynode,circle,myball-right color=violet](c42){Gebruiker versus consument}}
        child[visible on=<7->
] {node [mynode,circle,myball-right color=violet](c43){Design for disassembly}}
        child[visible on=<7->
] {node [mynode,circle,myball-right color=violet](c44){Circular financing}}
    }
    child [concept color=yellow,visible on=<8->
]{node [mynode,circle,myball-lefttop color=violet](c5){Prijssystemen}
        child[visible on=<9->
] {node [mynode,circle,myball-right color=violet](c51){Geld versus goed}}
        child[visible on=<9->
] {node [mynode,circle,myball-right color=violet](c52){Belasting en subsidies}}
        child[visible on=<9->
] {node [mynode,circle,myball-right color=violet](c53){Welzijn en groei}}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1) for `sibling angle=360/\the\tikznumberofchildren`. I'm wondering why that isn't default...

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement. Actually, I used it once before when working on my project and thus vividly knew that I should use the formula here when seeing the overlapping siblings. Well, my instinct response to your wonders is that for a two-sibling case a horizontal structure (if devaulted) takes more spaces than needed.

Answer (score 3):

Just removing `[clockwise from=45]` will solve the main problem:

[image: better behaved mindmap]